# Delete all products at once - BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to delete all products on BigCommerce eshop at once but it deletes only those products which are on the first page. [image]

When I click on the checkbox in the red circle, it selects products on current page so I can delete only 20 products.

Is it possible to delete them all at once? I've searched for this but can't find relevant information except those which are couple years old.

Comment: are you on a mac or windows?

Comment: I'm on windows but I think that it has nothing to do with it. Hasn't it?

Comment: Just wanted to get a better mental image. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page view to be higher to delete them from the UI or change the query string that the view count attaches once changed.

Alternatively, you can use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and send a DELETE request to the `/api/v2/products` endpoint.